# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'vue')

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Good afternoon!
I am new to Vue js and faced with the following problem:
When trying to launch a project, an error occurs: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'vue').
It occurred after trying to create and configure unit tests and installing css-loader and vue-loader. Before that, the project worked fine.
Moreover, it issues an error in different files (./src/App.vue, ./src/Dashboard.vue, etc...),
Below are the package.json, .babelrc and mian.js, please help me

package.json:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --open",
        "dev": "npm run serve",
        "build": "vue-cli-service build",
        "test": "mochapack --webpack-config build/webpack.base.conf.js --require test/setup.js test/**/*.spec.js",
        "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
        "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
        "chartist": "^0.11.0",
        "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^0.7.0",
        "ckeditor4-vue": "^1.1.0",
        "d3": "^5.7.0",
        "datamaps": "^0.5.9",
        "easy-pie-chart": "^2.1.7",
        "element-ui": "^2.4.11",
        "element-ui-el-table-draggable": "^1.2.10",
        "es6-promise": "^4.2.5",
        "fullcalendar": "^4.0.0-alpha.3",
        "fuse.js": "^3.2.0",
        "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
        "moment": "^2.22.1",
        "moment-timezone": "^0.5.32",
        "perfect-scrollbar": "0.7.1",
        "sweetalert2": "^7.33.1",
        "topojson": "^3.0.2",
        "v-clipboard": "^2.2.3",
        "v-tooltip": "^2.0.0-rc.33",
        "v-viewer": "^1.6.4",
        "vee-validate": "^2.1.5",
        "vue": "^2.5.21",
        "vue-chartjs": "^3.5.1",
        "vue-clickaway": "^2.2.2",
        "vue-form-wizard": "^0.8.1",
        "vue-nav-tabs": "^0.5.6",
        "vue-router": "^3.0.2",
        "vue2-slideout-panel": "^2.14.0",
        "vue2-transitions": "^0.2.3",
        "vuex": "^3.1.0",
        "vuex-persistedstate": "^2.5.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.2.2",
        "@vue/cli-service": "^3.2.3",
        "@vue/test-utils": "^1.3.0",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
        "babel-plugin-component": "^1.1.1",
        "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.2.0",
        "es6-promise": "^4.2.4",
        "eslint-config-standard": "^16.0.3",
        "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^4.0.1",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.2.0",
        "expect": "^27.5.1",
        "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
        "jsdom-global": "^3.0.2",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.6.2",
        "mocha": "^9.2.1",
        "mochapack": "^2.1.4",
        "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
        "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
        "vue-loader": "^13.0.4",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.21",
        "webpack": "^4.0.0"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": ">= 4.0.0",
        "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
    },
    "browserslist": [
        "> 1%",
        "last 2 versions",
        "not ie <= 10"
    ]
}
```

mian.js

```
import Vue from "vue"
import VueRouter from "vue-router"
import LightBootstrap from "./light-bootstrap-main"
import store from "./store"
import axios from "axios"
import moment from "moment-timezone"
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";

// Plugins
import App from "./App.vue"

// router setup
import routes from "./routes/routes"

// plugin setup
Vue.use(VueRouter)
Vue.use(LightBootstrap)

if (store.state.user.authenticated) {
    axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = store.state.user.token
}

axios.interceptors.request.use(async config => {
    if (store.state.user.authenticated) {
        axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = store.state.user.token
        let decoded = jwt_decode(store.state.user.token);
        let minutesLeft = (decoded.exp - moment().unix()) / 60

        if (config.url === "/api/tokenRefresh" || config.url === "/api/token") {
            return config
        }

        if (minutesLeft > 0 && minutesLeft <= 5) {
            axios({
                method: "post",
                url: "/api/tokenRefresh",
                data: {}
            })
                .then((response) => {
                    self.loading = false
                    let token = response.data.access_token
                    axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = token
                    store.commit("setToken", {
                        token: token
                    })
                    return axios(config);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error)
                    return axios(config);
                })
        }

    }
    return config
})


axios.defaults.headers.common["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
axios.defaults.headers.get["Pragma"] = "no-cache";
axios.defaults.headers.get["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store";

Vue.prototype.$axios = axios
Vue.prototype.moment = moment

// configure router
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: routes,
    linkActiveClass: "active"
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (store.state.user.authenticated && to.meta.hideForAuth) {
        next("/dashboard")
    }

    if ((to.meta && to.meta.open === true) || store.state.user.authenticated) {
        next()
    } else {
        next("/")
    }
})
/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    store: store,
    render: h => h(App),
    router: router
})
```

.babelrc

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@vue/app"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        [
            "component",
            {
                "libraryName": "element-ui",
                "styleLibraryName": "theme-chalk"
            }
        ],
        [
            "module-resolver",
            {
                "alias": {
                    "src": "./src"
                }
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Error:

```
Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                                                     22:20:40
 error  in ./src/App.vue

Syntax Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'vue')


 @ ./src/main.js 15:0-28 112:13-16
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.0.104:8080/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

Comment: You ran `npm install`?

Comment: of course! also removed node_modules and package-lock.json

Comment: Thanks for the help, I solved the problem in a different way, just installed unit tests according to the instructions in the finished project. [https://cli.vuejs.org/core-plugins/unit-jest.html#transform-dependencies-from-node-modules]